# EF Core LINQ can't translate schema submethod

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

We have a `BaseSchema` class which contains an `IEnumerable` of another schema which contains data for each language used by our application.

We wrote a helper method in the base schema which will get the property in the description schema for the supplied language or the first one with a value if none is found.

```
return await Context.Allergies
    .Include(allergy => allergy.Descriptions)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(allergy => new SynchronizableAllergyViewModel
    {
        Id = allergy.Id.ToString(),
        IsCommon = allergy.IsCommon,
        Name = allergy.GetTranslatedString(d => d.Name, Language),
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

```
public string GetTranslatedString(Func<TMultilingualSchema, string> stringParam, 
    TLanguageSchemaId languageId)
{
    return Descriptions
        .OrderBy(d => d.LanguageId.Equals(languageId) ? 0 : 1)
        .Select(stringParam)
        .FirstOrDefault(d => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d)) ?? string.Empty;
}
```

We are on .NET 6.0 with EF Core 6.0.16 on SQL Server.

When using the helper method, we get

> The LINQ expression 'd => d.Name' could not be translated

But, we can copy the method body in-place and get the expected result

```
return await Context.Allergies
    .Include(allergy => allergy.Descriptions)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .Select(allergy => new SynchronizableAllergyViewModel
    {
        Id = allergy.Id.ToString(),
        IsCommon = allergy.IsCommon,
        Name = allergy.Descriptions.OrderBy(d => d.LanguageId.Equals(Language) ? 0 : 1)
            .Select(d => d.Name)
            .FirstOrDefault(d => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d)) ?? string.Empty
    })
    .ToListAsync();
```

We tried to change the method to use Expressions and building the expression from the parameter name with no success.

When we try the "copy" solution on .NET 7 with EF Core 7.0.5, it gives the same result as the method call.

Comment: Why are you using `AsNoTracking()`? Are you aware that using it _does not_ significantly improve performance - and you know that it disables most of EF's most useful functionality?

Comment: It is used when we do not need to track the entities, in this case we return the data to the front-end so it's pointless to track

Comment: You can do not use `AsNoTracking`. EF Core do not track custom entities like `SynchronizableAllergyViewModel`. Anyway without third party extensions like LINQKit you cannot do that. If you OK to use them, I can provide solution.

Comment: @FrédéricBeaulieu So you're unaware that `AsNoTracking` breaks `Include()` as well as EF's ability to bind navigation properties with entities loaded in other queries, as well as breaking many types of `JOIN` (as EF can't correctly handle entities that exist as repeated rows - so it's not as simple as "only use `AsNoTracking()` if I'm not updating anything".

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv We are open to try it if it allows it to run entirely on the database

Comment: @Dai Thank you, but our current problem has nothing to do with `AsNoTracking`

Comment: What is the full type of `allergy.Descriptions`? What happens if you initially `await` loading `context.Allergies.Include( a => a.Descriptions ).ToListAsync()`, and _then_ create `SynchronizableAllergyViewModel` from that list?

Comment: `allergy.Descriptions` is a `IEnumerable<AllergyDescription>`. `AllergyDescription` has `Guid Id`, `Guid AllergyId`, `string Name` and `bool IsCommon`. If we `await` the result without the `Select`, then it would work. But the objective is to let SQL do the heavy lifting, which we know he is able to do when using the last snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit)

Prerequisites:

1. Install package [LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore). Select appropriate version depending on EF Core major version.
2. Activate `LINQKit` via options:

```cs
builder
    .UseSqlServer(connectionString)
    .WithExpressionExpanding(); // enabling LINQKit extension
```

Modify your method in the following way:

```cs
public class Allergy
{
    ... // other properties

    [Expandable(nameof(GetTranslatedStringImpl))]
    public string GetTranslatedString(Func<TMultilingualSchema, string> stringParam, 
        TLanguageSchemaId languageId)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    private static Expression<Func<Allergy, Func<TMultilingualSchema, string>, TLanguageSchemaId, string>> GetTranslatedStringImpl()
    {
        return (allergy, stringParam, languageId) => allergy.Descriptions
                .OrderBy(d => d.LanguageId.Equals(languageId) ? 0 : 1)
                .Select(stringParam)
                .FirstOrDefault(d => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d)) ?? string.Empty    
    }
}
```

After that you can use your method in LINQ Queries.